# How to add tabPanels to tabContainer on button click

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I have a tab container within an update panel. I'd like to add generated tabs to that container on a button click. The tabs get added. Once, the next time the button's clicked the previous tab is lost and a new one replaces it. I want to keep the tabs if possible. These tabs will later be filled with controls based on which button is clicked.

I've found many posts suggesting that the tabs have to be re-created on PostBack but it's not working. I don't think I know how to do it either.

My current aspx file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add Tab" />
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" 
                    ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code-behind so far.

```
Imports AjaxControlToolkit

Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub WebForm1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim newTab As TabPanel = New TabPanel
        Dim rand As New Random
        Dim exampleID As String = rand.Next(1000).ToString
        newTab.ID = exampleID
        newTab.HeaderText = exampleID
        newTab.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(exampleID))
        TabContainer1.Tabs.Add(newTab)
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "<br />" + "Added tab " + newTab.ID.ToString 'Just here for output.
    End Sub

End Class
```

I'm sure the current open tabs have to be stored somewhere and re-created on the update panel's postback but like I said. Where do I put that code and how is it stored?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!